# Is it possible to take a screenshot/PDF of part of the page? for ex. a particular div?

Tags: google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

I tried to use Phantomjs for taking screenshots of my SPA. As per my requirement, i should be able to take screenshot of part of the page rather than whole page. The png/image works fine with phantom but the PDF is not working. I'm trying to see if it's possible to do a part of the page(not the whole page) as PDF export with Puppeteer. I checked their documentation but nowhere it was mentioned.
Has anybody tried to achieve the same with puppeteer?
 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, you can take screenshots of specific parts of the screen using the clip options for the `screenshot` method. You can read about it in the [docs here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagescreenshotoptions).

It's not possible to do the same with the `pdf` method. The relevant [docs are here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions).